# emacs - render newlines

Tags: logging, emacs

I'm using emacs to view php error logs. The problem is that it's very hard to read when multiple lines are logged. It looks something like this:

```
[Fri Aug 15 14:55:02 2014] [error] [client 10.10.10.10] WC_Checkout Object\n(\n    [posted] => \n    [checkout_fields] => Array\n        (\n            [billing] => Array\n                (\n       \
             [billing_country] => Array\n                        (\n                            [type] => country\n                            [label] => Country\n                            [required\
] => 1\n                            [class] => Array\n                                (\n
```

OSX has the console log viewer program that formats log files with newlines nicely. Is there anyway I can get emacs (or use another terminal log viewing program) that formats multi-line errors properly? i.e. something like below instead of the above:

```
[Fri Aug 15 14:55:02 2014] [error] [client 67.161.204.87] 
   WC_Checkout Object
   (    
   [posted] => 
        [checkout_fields] => Array
        (
            [billing] => Array
            (
                 billing_country] => Array
                 (
                     [type] => country
                     [label] => Country
                     [required] => 1
                 )
            )
         )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `\n` with the newline by doing:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-string` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\n` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>.

Comment: That worked - but is there anyway I can add something to the .emacs file so it does this automatically when I'm viewing .log files - or any files that contain a '\n'?